# VS local debugging throws 'Name or service not known (login.windows.net:443)'

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Somewhere out of the blue, our project started throwing this exception.
We have over 10 microservices that were all functioning fine, but now suddenly can no longer run locally.

[image: Exception thrown]

It happens at the `builder.Build()` when trying to retrieve variables from the `appsettings.json`  to connect to our keyvault in azure.

This problem was non-existant about a month ago. Then started happening 50% of the time while trying to start up the application locally using `docker`. And since today, it happens 100% of the time. Making it impossible to run locally.

Deploying the code to our Azure environment works without a problem. The service starts up without a problem and works 100% as intended.

I have searched far and wide, but cannot find anyone that has had this problem before.

I suspect it has something to do with docker not being able to connect to azure. I have atleast 2 other team members who have been experiencing the exact same thing. One of them can still run it locally (receives this error 50% of the time), while the other one can't (error 100% of the time).

Code that throws the exception (this is in a library and used by all the microservices).

```
public static IHostBuilder UseKeyVault(this IHostBuilder host, string environment)
{
    host.SetKeyVault(_SharedKeyVault); // A shared keyvault containing keys used across multiple services 
    host.SetKeyVault(GetKeyVault(environment)); // Development/Staging/Production prefix

    return host;
}


private static IHostBuilder SetKeyVault(this IHostBuilder host, string keyVault)
{
    host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
    {
        var config = builder.Build(); // Exception thrown here
        builder.AddAzureKeyVault(
            $"https://{keyVault}.vault.azure.net/", config["KeyVault:ClientId"],
            config["KeyVault:ClientSecret"]);
    });

    return host;
}
```

**Full trace of exception:**
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
HResult=0x80004005
Message=Name or service not known (login.windows.net:443)
Source=System.Net.Http
StackTrace:
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.d__1.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.d__82.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.d__86.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.d__67.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.d__72.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.d__4.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsyncCore>d__85.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.HttpClientWrapper.<GetResponseAsync>d__30.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.<GetResponseAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.<GetResponseAsync>d__20`1.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<SendHttpMessageAsync>d__67.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__64.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<RunAsync>d__55.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.d__49.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__26.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions.d__21.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.<PostAuthenticate>d__9.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.d__10.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.d__66.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.<GetSecretsAsync>d__49.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.<LoadAsync>d__11.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.Load() at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
at ChainCargo.Security.ChainCargoSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(System.Net.Sockets.SocketError, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(short)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ConnectAsync.__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|283_0(System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs, System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.DefaultConnectAsync(System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpConnectionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
...
[Call Stack Truncated]

Inner Exception 1:
SocketException: Name or service not known

Answer (score 1):

We managed to solve the issue by downgrading our docker version. Version 4.0.0 and 4.0.1 gave us this issue.
After uninstalling latest and then installing 3.5.1, we could again run locally without any issues.